# Show spinner while loading an iframe in a facebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebox

I am using jQuery [facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) to open a new window for authenticating Facebook users with [Devise/Omniauth](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) in my rails app.

At first I wanted to simply load this in a div like so:

```
$('#facebook-auth').live 'click', ->       
  $.facebox '<div id="foo"></div>'
  $('#foo').load $(this).attr 'href'
  false
```

But the problem is that this will not work because there are multiple redirects. The first link opens `/auth/facebook`, which redirects to `graph.facebook.com`, which redirects back to my callback url, which finally redirects to a confirmation page. I need to display the confirmation page to the user. The way I have it working right now is by opening an external window like this:

```
$('#facebook-auth').live 'click', ->
  width = 600
  height = 400
  left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2)
  top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2)
  window.open $(this).attr('href'), 'authPopup', "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=#{width},height=#{height},toolbar=no,left=#{left},top=#{top}"
  false
```

Is there a way for me to open a new window and load its contents in the facebox? Or is there a better approach?

**Edit**

Thanks to Jared's suggestion I was able to do this using an iFrame mod from [here](http://lnx.shortcutto701.com/2010/05/21/using-iframe-with-facebox-jquery-plugin/). See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AExpj/). However I would like to show the loading spinner while the iframe content is loading. Is this possible? According to the documentation, the way to do it normally is like this:

```
$(".badge").live "click", ->
  $.facebox ->
    $.get "page.html", (data) ->
      $.facebox data
  false
```

But I'm not sure how to do this with the iframe mod.

Comment: You could use an IFRAME in the Facebox I believe.

Comment: do you control the confirmation page?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try this css trick.. is this what you are trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/7CBjn/3/

```
iframe {
    background-image: url("http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading2.gif");   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Note that the loading gif is no longer working... so anyone who tries this, just link to a new image when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can probably show a spinner, then constantly check if an iframe finished loading, or use iframe's onload event handler.

Not completely sure how will it work with redirects, but you could try smth like [that](http://www.tipstrs.com/tip/3126/Telling-when-an-iframe-is-done-loading).

Comment: The link provided is broken.